# Javascript canvas, angulo de movimiento de un elemento

Tags: javascript, canvas

Estoy aprendiendo a mover objetos de un canvas mediante javascript.
El siguiente código crea una bola que rebota en los margenes del canvas. No termino de entender porque la bola se mueve en ese angulo en particular y como podría cambiarlo.
El Código es un ejemplo que copié y modifiqué brevemente.
Puede verse el ejemplo en https://jsfiddle.net/smscarano/rkanqehL/

```
window.onload = function(){
            let body_width = document.body.clientWidth;
            let body_height = document.body.clientHeight;
            let col_canvas_width = document.getElementById('canvas_div').clientWidth;
            let col_canvas_height = document.getElementById('canvas_div').clientHeight;

            let canvas = document.createElement("CANVAS");
            canvas_div.appendChild(canvas);
            canvas.id = "myCanvas";
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            var ballRadius = 10;
            var x = canvas.width/2;
            var y = canvas.height/2;
            var dx = 3;
            var dy = -3;

            function drawBall() {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.arc(x, y, ballRadius, 0, Math.PI*2);
                ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
                ctx.fill();
                ctx.closePath();
            }

            function draw() {
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                drawBall();
                if(x + dx > canvas.width-ballRadius || x + dx < ballRadius) {
                    dx = -dx;
                }
                if(y + dy > canvas.height-ballRadius || y + dy < ballRadius) {
                    dy = -dy;
                }
                x += dx;
                y += dy;
            }

            setInterval(draw, 10);
        };
```

Comment: Encontré la respuesta, var dx = 3;  var dy = -3; definen la velocidad, utilizando diferentes valores cambia el angulo de moviento. Gracias

Comment: Es lo que responde Alfredo Maussa  @sms en su respuesta no?, te sugerimos revisar [tour], si la respuesta soluciona el problema puedes marcarla como solución.

Comment: @Jorgesys , Él Se respondió primero en el comentario, como estaba escribiendo la respuesta en ese momento pues la terminé de editar y la agregué después de su propio comentario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El ángulo con el que se mueve es el resultado de cuantos pixeles se desplaza en *x* y *y* por cada iteración.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Nota:** dy está "al revés" ya que en programación es común que el 0 quede en la parte superior de la pantalla, mientras cada pixel se cuenta hacia abajo.

En el código que compartes *dx* representa el cambio de pixeles en horizontal por iteración, y *dy* representa el cambio de pixeles en vertical.

Una forma de asociar con trigonometría es teniendo en cuenta la siguiente fórmula, la cual expresa una relación entre el ángulo y el cambio de pixeles en *x* y *y*:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En tu caso si es 3-3 pixeles en x-y, entonces el ángulo inicial es 45°.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Acepté la respuesta de Alfredo Maussa por ser tan clara. Muchas gracias.